# How much damage does Magic Weapon, Greater- and Crystal Magic Weapon add?

Tags: dark-souls

All three sorceries add magic damage to your weapon assuming the weapon can be enchanted. 
Is there a formula that shows exactly how much damage such an enchantment provides (and does it vary with weapon types)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Magic Weapon:](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/magic-weapon) Adds magic damage to right hand weapon. Magic damage added is (catalyst's MagAdjust * 0.8)

[Great Magic Weapon:](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/great-magic-weapon) Adds magic damage to right hand weapon. Magic damage added is (catalyst's MagAdjust * 1.1)

[Crystal Magic Weapon:](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/crystal-magic-weapon) Adds magic damage to right hand weapon. Magic damage added is (catalyst's MagAdjust * 1.4)

And the list of [catalysts](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/catalysts).

So to answer, the added damage is entirely dependent on the quality of the catalyst, and weapon type does not matter.